# Laravel log info debug class name and line number

Tags: laravel-5.4

Is there any hack to present the  class name and line number for log info and debug.

log4j and log4net has that from day one.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be possible using PHPs ReflectionClass. I've never tried this so I'm just taking a guess here.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php

I know Symfony/Laravel rely heavily on it to perform the internal class resolution and bindings.